# Wpf Tool Window Style Application not visible in alt+tab

Tags: wpf, windows, styles

I have a WPF application with

1. Main Window which is not a tool window
2. Launch a child window which has **WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ShowInTaskbar="False"** from main window

Now BOTH Main Window and Child Window are not visible in Alt+Tab. [Child window not appearing in alt+tab is expected behavior,but Main window should be visible]

Any help would be appreciated.
Related link:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/95e076a3-3030-4dc0-ab23-a7e489b2a160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as expected on my machine (Windows 7) when using *Show*:

```
Window child = new Window();
child.Owner = this;

child.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;

child.ShowInTaskbar = false;
child.Show();
```

When using *ShowDialog*, the issue occurs. However, I am wondering whether it makes sense to show a ToolWindow as Dialog - Tool Windows are usually no dialogs.

Comment: you are right.But we have a requirement to mimic Outlook 2003 GAL window,which does not have "Minimize" and "Maximize" button.The only way to achieve this is to making it as tool window which causes alt+tab problem.
The work around for this problem so far is to use win32 API to set window styles.
Is there any way of using WPF styles to archive the same style as tool window.