# How to hide a WPF Window icon and use ResizeMode=NoResize?

Tags: c#, wpf

I recently implemented the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580430/hide-the-icon-from-a-wpf-window) to hide a WPF Window's icon. I found that when that solution is used in conjunction with `ResizeMode=NoResize`, the app's title bar context menu fails to disable Min/Max/Resize options.

The odd thing is the context menu doesn't incorrectly enable certain options, it just leaves the state of the context menu from before the icon was hidden. I found this using a simple test app that can make the necessary calls to hide the icon, and can update the Window's `ResizeMode` on the fly.

**Icon Shown, ResizeMode=CanResize**

Title bar buttons and context menu are correct.

[image]

**Icon Hidden, ResizeMode=CanResize**

Still correct

[image]

**Icon Hidden, ResizeMode=NoResize**

Title bar buttons are correctly hidden, but the context menu retains it's previous state. If I switch to `CanMinimize` then to `NoResize`, the context menu would only have "Minimize" enabled.

[image]

This becomes a problem when a resize-able WPF Window launches another Window which is set to `NoResize` (and you are hiding the icon).

**Question**

Are there additional Windows API functions that can force the Context Menu to reevaluate its state? What about the `NoResize` option might be causing this weird behavior? As this only affects the `NoResize` option, could there be a workaround at the WPF level?

EDIT - My goal is to avoid using `WindowStyle=ToolWindow` or the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` extended window style. I've found a few problems with that window style in the past, one is desribed [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146230/wpf-tool-window-style-application-not-visible-in-alttab). One of my goals with this whole approach was to emulate the look of `ToolWindow` without actually having to use it.

Comment: Which solution did you adopt? o-toole-kit's or Sheridan's one?

Comment: A combination. I do `SetWindowLong...SendMessage...SendMessage...SetWindowPos`. Using just one or the other didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Using .NET 4.0 and Windows 8.1 Enterprise (I do not know if it works with other .NET versions or a different OS), you just need to use the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` extended style instead of the `WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME` one.

So the code will be:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int width, int height, uint flags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    private const int WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME = 0x0001;
    private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    private const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    private const int SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
    private const int WM_SETICON = 0x0080;
    private const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

        int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);

        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, new IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero);
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

        SetWindowPos(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | 
            SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }
}
```

Let's hope it can help you.

Comment: I think this is a valid answer but I'm trying to avoid using `ToolWindow`. As described [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146230/wpf-tool-window-style-application-not-visible-in-alttab), `ToolWindow` has some undesirable side effects. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: I am afraid there is no other way @Michael if you want to use `SetWindowLong`. Did you consider creating an empty icon and using it for your window?

Comment: That's probably the way we'll go for the time being. When a window is set to use  `NoResize`, just display a stub transparent icon instead of hiding it. Not ideal, but ya probably the best for now.